# Upper and lower limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following lemma

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence with lower limit $\underline{x}$ and upper limit $\overline{x}$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have
>   $$
> \underline{x}-\epsilon<x_n<\overline{x}+\epsilon
> $$

Why does it follow from this lemma that there is a $K_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\geq K_1$ we have $\overline{x}_k<\epsilon$?

Upper limit $\overline{x}$ is

$$
\overline{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{x}_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{x_m:m\geq n\}
$$

Lower limit $\underline{x}$ is

$$
\underline{x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underline{x}_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\{x_m:m\geq n\}
$$

**Context:** I am reading the proof of lemma 3 [in this document](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~frank/0413/ullimits.pdf)
and my question is a statement in the proof of lemma 3.

Comment: What are lower limit and upper limit?

Comment: @MyGlasses: I edited my question to answer your question.

Comment: What is $\overline x_k$?

Comment: "we have $\bar x_k<\epsilon$" looks wrong. Typo?

Comment: @drhab: see http://www.math.pitt.edu/~frank/0413/ullimits.pdf I am reading the proof of lemma 3

Comment: @grand_chat: see proof of lemma 3 in http://www.math.pitt.edu/~frank/0413/ullimits.pdf

Comment: I looked at your link. If I'm looking at the right place, it's an error. Should read "$\bar x_k<\bar x + \epsilon$"

Comment: @grand_chat: I do not think that I have miscopied it. The proof of Lemma 3 on page 2 of that document says "It follows from Lemma 1 that there is a $K_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\geq K_1$ we
have $\overline{x}_k<\epsilon$". You do not see that?

Comment: I edited my comment. Please refresh it

Comment: It is a typo in that lemma 3.

Comment: @grand_chat: Can you explain then why is $\overline{x}\leq\overline{x}_k$ when $\overline{x}_k$ is decreasing?

Comment: $\bar x$ is by def the limit of $\bar x_k$. If a sequence is decreasing (which is true for $\bar x_k$) then its limit is $\le$ any term in the sequence.

Comment: @grand_chat: Thanks a lot. I have one last question. In the proof of lemma 3, I do not understand anything after displayed equation (2). Can you explain it to me?

Comment: I wrote an answer to fill in a few gaps in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's detailed commentary on the proof of Lemma 3.

**Lemma 3 (first half).** *Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence with upper limit $\bar x$. For every $\epsilon>0$ and every $k\in{\mathbb N}$, there exists $n>K$ such that*
$$|x_n-\bar x|<\epsilon.$$

*Proof*: Since the sequence $\bar x_k$ decreases to $\bar x$, there exists $K_1$ such that for all $k\ge K_1$,
$$
\bar x \le \bar x_k<\bar x + \epsilon.\tag{1}
$$
Fix any $k\ge K_1$. Recall that $\bar x_k:=\sup\{x_k, x_{k+1}, x_{k+2},\ldots \}$ by definition. So the left-hand inequality in (1) is a statement that the sup of a certain set exceeds a certain value. Earlier you should have proved a result similar to:

> If $\sup A\ge b$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an element $x\in A$ such that $x>b-\epsilon$.

Applying this result to the LHS of (1), we assert that there exists $n\ge k$ such that
$$
x_n >\bar x - \epsilon.\tag2
$$
For this $n$ we also have
$$
x_n\stackrel{(*)}\le \sup\{x_k, x_{k+1}, x_{k+2},\ldots \}=:\bar x_k\stackrel{(1)}<\bar x + \epsilon,\tag3
$$
where (*) follows from the fact that

> $x\le \sup A$ for every $x\in A$.

To recap, we've established that for every $k\ge K_1$ there exists $n\ge k$ such that
$$\bar x -\epsilon\stackrel{(2)}< x_n\stackrel{(3)}<\bar x + \epsilon.\tag4$$
Going back to the statement of the Lemma, the claim is that for any $K$ we can find $n$ such that $n$ exceeds $K$ and $n$ satisfies (4). We haven't even talked about $K$ yet, so this constraint on $n$ hasn't been enforced yet, but we can do so by requiring the $k$ we originally fixed to exceed not just $K_1$ but also $K$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I spent yesterday the whole day to understand lemma 3.